# ASP Login Control stop execution on onLoggingIn method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, login-control

As a newbie, seeking help for the below scenario.

I am using ASP LoginView control, and have the corresponding event handlers.
For every incorrect login attempt, I am storing the attempt count and user details, If max count is reached I disable the user. When the user tries to Login next time, i check if the user is enabled/disabled and if disabled need to stop the execution and block the login action.

I tried to use

> return;

in the onLoggingIn method but this does not stop the execution and still continues the login action.

ASPX Code :

```
<asp:loginView id="loginView" runat="server">
<AnonymousTemplate>
<asp:login id="login1" runat="server"
OnLoggedIn="Login1_onLoggedIn"
OnLoggingIn="Login1_onLoggingIn"
OnLoginError="Login1_onLoginError"
<LayoutTemplate>
<asp:Textbox ID="username" runat="server" />
<asp:Textbox ID="password" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID = "LoginButton" runat="server" Command="Login" />
</LayoutTemplate>
</asp:login>
</AnonymousTemplate>
</asp:loginView>
```

CS Code:

```
protected void Page_load(object sender,EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void Login1_onLoggingIn(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
// This method is called when user clicked on Login Button.
// Checking if the user is enabled or disabled. 
// If user disabled - show error message and need to stop the execution here and not go further
// Tried return; - but execution still continue.
}

protected void Login1_onLoggedIn(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
// This method is called when user is logged.
}

protected void Login1_onLoginError(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
// This method is called on incorrect login attempt and store the count and user detail in DB
// If max incorrect login attempts reached, user marked as disabled for specific time limit.
}
```

If anyone can guide how can I check the user enabled/disabled and if user disabled, how can I stop the method execution and prevent the flow to continue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For cancelling the execution of the `OnLoggingIn` method, you may use the `CancelEventArgs.Cancel` property:

```
protected void Login1_onLoggingIn(object sender,System.Web.UI.WebControls.LoginCancelEventArgs e)
{
   var userDisabled= CheckIfUserIsDisabled(); //Implement this
 if (isUserDisabled)
    {
        // Show an error message.
        login1.FailureText = "Your account is disabled";
        e.Cancel = true;// Here is the point
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @MD Zand. This works like a charm.
However when i set the value for login1.FailureText , the text is not visible on UI.
I have exactly as shown in your response.

Comment: If you want to display the text use the `ErrorMessage` property instead. By the way: check the tick mark beside this answer to make it the accepted one if it helped.

Comment: I tried, but could'nt find the login1.ErrorMessage property to set for display.
There is a EventHandler LoginError